# What is the transformation math for creating a 45 deg angle drop shadow?

Tags: image, math, google-maps

I read somewhere in Google's reference (and I can not find it again) that the shadow for the map marker should be at a 45 degree angle. What is the transformation to apply to the original image to achieve this? By eyeball it looks like it could be a horizontal shear of about 50% followed by a vertical compression to 50%, but I suspect it could be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the answer, but this website painlessly eliminated the problem.

http://cycloloco.com/shadowmaker/

Comment: According to the site, it's a 0.5 y scale and pi/4 shear, which I believe is equivalent to the matrix `[ 2 1 / 0 1 ]`